# .htaccess external & internal rewrite conflict

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to rewrite a query string to a path, like so:

```
http://example.com/?p=page1
```

to

```
http://example.com/page/page1
```

The internal redirect works and I can view the page at the second URL but as soon as I try to redirect the first URL to the second, I get a 'Too many redirects' error.

.htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /page/(.*)
RewriteRule page/(.*)$ index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /page/%1? [R=301,L,NE,QSD,NC]
```

The first two lines are working by themeselves. The addition of the last two lines causes the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rule is redirecting the uri back it itself that is why you got the redirect error.
You can use `%{THE_REQUEST}` or `%{ENV_REDIRECT_STATUS}` variables to avoid `Too many redirect` error .

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /page/(.*)
RewriteRule page/(.*)$ index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteCond %{ENV_REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /page/%1? [R=301,L,NE,QSD,NC]
```

or

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /page/(.*)
RewriteRule page/(.*)$ index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /\?p=.+ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /page/%1? [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: Using `{THE_REQUEST}` worked perfectly. Thank you very much for your help.